# Will Kivy / Buildozer apps run on Android 11 Go edition?

Tags: kivy, buildozer, android-go

Just getting started on my first Python app for Android so I am shopping for a basic tablet to test on but I see the cheap ones use **Android 11 'Go edition'** which appears to be Android lite.

I cannot find any mention of Android Go edition in Kivy or Buildozer documentation.

Do I need to be concerned about this?

Do I need to  purchase a more expensive tablet using full Android 11 or will Go edition work fine for me?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Why would it not work?

Comment: Since you asked: It seems reasonable to assume that the Go edition has limited functionality to run on low memory platforms and I see that some apps even have 'go' versions.